# Dynamically import components for static site generation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a dynamic page tree, each page with its own content using different components.

The pages are being statically pre-rendered on build using Next.js' static site generation. I use the following component to handle the population of components:

```
import React from "react";
import { Data } from "../../types/data";
import { Block } from "../../css/content";

const componentList: Record<string, any> = {
    BlockA: require("../molecule/BlockA").BlockA,
    BlockB: require("../molecule/BlockB").BlockB,
    BlockC: require("../organism/BlockC").BlockC,
    BlockD: require("../molecule/BlockD").BlockD,
    BlockE: require("../organism/BlockE").BlockE,
    BlockF: require("../atom/BlockF").BlockF,
    BlockG: require("../organism/BlockG").BlockG,
    ...
};

interface TemplateProps {
    data: Data.Main;
    props?: any;
}

export const Template: React.FC<TemplateProps> = ({ data, props = {} }) => {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            {data.content.map((item, index) => {
                const Component = componentList[item.component.type];

                if (!Component) return null;

                return (
                    <Block key={index}>
                        <Component {...item.component} {...props} />
                    </Block>
                );
            })}
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};
```

This works fine, but imports all blocks, even if they are not need for a specific page, increasing the first load js size. How can I prevent that from happening and **dynamically import components on demand, on build**?

Using `next/dynamic` kind of solves that issue, but AFAIK prevents the component from being statically pre-rendered - and we don't want to miss out on that.

Comment: By chance, have you tried [dynamic imports](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import)?

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov Yes, but AFAIK dynamic import will take place in client and won't be pre-rendered on build.

Comment: "dynamic import will take place in client" - that's only true if you pass `ssr: false` in the `next/dynamic` call.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`React.lazy`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactlazy)

```js
import React from "react";
import { Data } from "../../types/data";
import { Block } from "../../css/content";

const componentList: Record<string, any> = {
  BlockA: React.lazy(() => import("../molecule/BlockA").BlockA)
};

interface TemplateProps {
  data: Data.Main;
  props?: any;
}

export const Template: React.FC<TemplateProps> = ({ data, props = {} }) => {
  return (


    <React.Suspense fallback={<div>loading</div>}>

      {data.content.map((item, index) => {
        const Component = componentList[item.component.type];

        if (!Component) return null;

        return (
          <Block key={index}>
            <Component {...item.component} {...props} />
          </Block>
        );
      })}
    </React.Suspense>
  );
};
```

Please keep in mind, you need to use `React.lazy` along with `React.Suspense`.